# Calculating Average Rate of Return

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am having a hard time on my homework with understanding how to calculate the average rate of return for an investment. After calculating the average rate of return is explained to me, I want to solve the problem in my homework on my own, so here is an example that I made from the top of my head.

> An investment earns 16% its first year, 2% its second, and loses 5% it's third. 
>   How much would a $2000 investment be worth at the end of three years? What is 
>   the average rate of return?"

---

Here is my attempt at explaining what I think is right.

To determine what the investment would be worth after three years, you would do:

$2000 \times 1.16 \times 1.02 \times 0.05 = 118.32$

To find average rate of return, you would do:

$\sqrt[3]{1.16 \times 1.02 \times 0.05} = .3896512332$

Is this right?

Comment: No, the .05 would assume a loss of 95% as each return is (1+r) where r is the percent return which would be .16 for the first year, .02 for the second and -.05 for the third.

Comment: On the rate of return, you need to remove the initial 1 that was put into it. The average rate of return is .3896512332-1 approximately as the value is likely to be an irrational number that you are rounding off.

Comment: @JBKing So my the first part should be `2000 * 1.16 * 1.02 * 0.95` and my second should be `³√(1.16 * 1.02 * 0.05)` as it is now?

Comment: The first part is right. The second part should be ³√(1.16 * 1.02 * 0.95) - 1

Comment: Consider the case where you had 0% return for 3 straight years. The end value would be 2000 dollars as this is $ 2000*1*1*1 $ and the average return would be $ (1*1*1)^\frac{1}{3}-1=1-1=0 $ which is 0% that should make sense.

Comment: @JBKing Oooh! I get it now! Thanks! If you repost what you've just told me as an answer I'll accept it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the investment is worth in the end is computed this way:

$2000*(1+16/100)*(1+2/100)*(1-5/100) = 2000 * 1.16 * 1.02 * 0.95 = 2248.08$

Thus, there is a gain of 248.08 in the end.

To find average rate of return, you would do:

$³√(1.16 * 1.02 * 0.95) - 1 = ³√(1.12404) - 1 = 1.0397459931939351874765829661942 - 1 = .0397$

3.97% is the average rate of return.